# WordPress WooCommerce email notifications going to spam folder

Tags: email, dns

I have just built a new WordPress site for a client, and repointed the domain's ([mellowmarshfarm.com](https://mellowmarshfarm.com)) DNS records to the new hosting service, Flywheel.

The client's custom email address is hosted by a different provider, and the notifications for the site are forwarded from WordPress via `fw-mail.com`, but they are going to the client's and customers' spam folders. I have tried adding `x.fw-mail.com` to the mail host's SPF record, but it didn't make a difference:

```
v=spf1 ip4:[redacted] include:spf.antispamcloud.com include:x.fw-mail.com +a +mx ~all
```

What else must I do to ensure the emails are associated with the new site and validated?

Comment: this is something your host can help with, but keep in mind hosts aren't a great option for reliably sending emails, especially if it concerns ecommerce or money. A hosts reputation can be downranked by any of their customers, so regardless of how trustworthy your business is, Flywheel as a whole and all their customers are what's considered, regardless of wether it's confirmed via DNS that they did indeed come from flywheel. Email and DNS is outside this stacks scope though. Consider looking into SMTP plugins if your host is not also your email provider as that's a red flag they look for

Comment: Thanks for your useful comments, Tom. I'll look into SMTP plugins.